# Longest Prefix query in elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene, amazon-elasticsearch

I am trying to do a longest prefix query in Elasticsearch. My requirement is that suppose I have the numbers

```
12356
12345
33332
```

in elastic search and I query **1234567** It should return the number with the longest sequence of common characters. In this case it is 12345. I search online for some solution but they all require scripts is elastic search. I am using AWS Elasticservice and this query has to be queried on AWS. AWS doesnot allow the usage of scripts for "security reasons". Is there any way to achieve this query without the use of script?

Comment: [Ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html) (see also, [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)) should get pretty close to the mark here.

Comment: I saw that, but I can only create ngrams of the data in elastic search and then search a string against the ngrams. I want something inverse of this. I have a long string and I need to check if any of the strings in ES is a substring of the given query string.

Comment: Then make it your [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html).